# How to bypass an overriding CSS Declaration

Tags: css

***UPDATE: Please see my answer below***

I am trying to use the properties from the first `.alert` CSS declaration on a `div` *even though the first declaration is being overridden by a subsequent declaration*.

**CSS**

```
.alert{ margin:10px; } // one.css
.alert{ margin:0; } // two.css
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="alert">Hello!</div>
```

Do you know if there there is any way that I can handle this situation *without having to create another declaration to override the declaration in two.css*?

I searched Google and SO but I am unable to find a solution to this.

**Edit:** If I make the first declaration `!important` or increase its specificity then I will break the use of the second .alert declaration. So unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: I think you should use another class if you don't want to make the first CSS rule `!important`

Comment: how about `!important`?

Comment: do you want to do it on one/few pages only, and the rest leave as it is?

Comment: You can't do what you're looking to without giving the element a distinct class or ID.

Comment: On any particular page

Comment: @j08691 if you believe that it is impossible then please write that as an answer and I will mark it as the accepted answer. This may very well be a limitation of CSS or poor practice on my part.

Comment: @j08691 I'm sorry, I just realized that I think you are misunderstanding the question. For I can surely add another class or ID to the div without a problem.

Comment: No, I'm not misunderstanding what you want to do. You simply cannot do it without adding a distinct class or ID to this element you refer to. Overriding it with specificity or `!important` will affect all elements that it matches -- there's no way to selectively override that.

Comment: @Andy alright, please post that as an additional answer so that I can accept it. I agree with you, I think that the messy inheritance problem that I am having is an edge case because of poor practice. I was just looking for a band-aid which I suppose is indeed not possible.

Comment: @j08691 I'm sorry, it's hard to explain why but I really think that there is a misunderstanding. It could be my fault

Comment: Why not use an inline style for your specific div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the general consensus, bypassing CSS inheritance is not possible. I would need to do one of two things to get the style originally applied by the first declaration:

1. Make the first declaration more specific or !important
2. Override the second declaration with a third

This seems to be a case of poor practice in CSS, so if you encounter a similar issue, then please take a moment to consider the way you are setting up your style sheets.

I am going to try and work out my own situation in another manner and if I have anything of value to share perhaps I will return to provide some more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use `!important`.

```
.alert{ margin:10px !important; } // one.css
.alert{ margin:0; } // two.css
```

Or make the declaration more specific than in `two.css`. Or load `one.css` after `two.css`.

Comment: Some `divs` need the margin to be zero, so making the first one `!important` will break that.

Answer (score 0):

Reference the parent id selector before your class name, to make that class property take dominate value. If you don't have a parent Id, then create one.  You won't have to relay on using !important, as that does not work properly in every situation.

Something like this...

```
#parent .alert { margin:10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the first CSS rule applied to an element and store it and then later get the computed value and compare. If the values are not the same you can set the element to the original values.

Here is a function that loops through css rules and gets the value of the style you specify. You will have to modify it to include classes (it currently checks by ID) and to save the original declaration.

You could also create a new rule with only the values you want to include and apply it to the specic elements.

```
function getCSSPropertyValueForElement(id, property) {
    var styleSheets = document.styleSheets;
    var numOfStylesheets = styleSheets.length;
    var values = [];
    var selectorText = "#" + id;
    var value;

    for(var i=0;i<numOfStylesheets;i++) {
        var styleSheet = styleSheets[i];
        var cssRules = styleSheet.cssRules;
        var numOfCSSRules = cssRules.length;
        var cssRule;

        for (var j=0;j<numOfCSSRules;j++) {
            cssRule = cssRules[j];

            if (cssRule.media) {
                var mediaRules = cssRule.cssRules;
                var numOfMediaRules = mediaRules ? mediaRules.length : 0;

                for(var k=0;k<numOfMediaRules;k++) {
                    var mediaRule = mediaRules[k];

                    if (mediaRule.selectorText==selectorText) {

                        if (mediaRule.style && property in mediaRule.style) {
                            value = mediaRule.style.getPropertyValue(property);
                            console.log(property+":" + value);
                            values.push(value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {

                if (cssRule.selectorText==selectorText) {
                    if (cssRule.style && property in cssRule.style) {
                        value = cssRule.style.getPropertyValue(property);
                        console.log(property+":" + value);
                        values.push(value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return values.pop();
}

var property = "outline";
// getting the computed value / current value
var value = window.getComputedValue(element, "stylenamedoesntwork").style[property];
```